# Importing data from csv into R, column not populated

Tags: r, csv

I am new to R programming. I have imported a csv file using the following function

```
PivotTest <- read.csv(file.choose(), header=T)
```

The csv file has 7 columns: Meter_Serial_No, Reading_Date, Reading_Description, Reading_value, Entry_Processed, TS_Inserted, TS_LastUpdated.

When uploading, the Meter_Serial_No is filled with zero while there are data in that column in the csv file. When running a function to see what data are in that particular column `(PivotTest$Meter_Serial_No)`, it's returning NULL. Can anyone assist me please.

Furthermore, the csv that I'm importing has more than 127,000 rows. When doing a test with 10 rows of data only, I don't have that problem where the column Meter_Serial_No is replaced with zero.

Comment: The column is filled with zero?  That sounds like data to me.  Can you please be more specific, and provide a **small** example of the file

Comment: can you post a copy of the CSV file somewhere, or edit your question to post an *exact* excerpt of the first few lines?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the class of values which are there in the column   (PivotTest$Meter_Serial_No). I believe there is a problem in type conversion, try the following.

```
PivotTest <- read.csv("test.csv", header=T,colClasses=c(PivotTest$Meter_Serial_No="character",rep("numeric",6)))
```

Comment: This issue seems to be occuring only with RStudio. I'm not encountering the issue when running on RConsole

Comment: we really need a reproducible example to be able to help you get any farther with this.